# Problems with Group By R

Tags: r, group-by

```
library(Lahman)
bat_01 <- Batting %>% filter(yearID %in% 1999:2001) %>%
  mutate(pa = AB + BB, singles = (H - X2B - X3B - HR)/pa, bb = BB/pa) %>%
  filter(pa >= 100) %>%
  select(playerID, singles, bb) %>% 
  group_by(playerID, .add =TRUE) %>%
  mutate(mean_singles = mean(singles), mean_bb = mean(bb) ) %>%
  filter(mean_bb > 0.2)
bat_01
```

The grouping does not work properly. If you run the code you can see repetitive player IDs. Can anyone help me to understand what's the problem.

Comment: BTW I am a beginner in the field. So, I hope for your understanding, in case I made any mistakes with the format of the question. Please, tell me and I will try to correct it!

Comment: try `distinct(playerID, .keep_all=T)` after `select()`

Comment: I guess the 'problem' is, that you have still the columns ```singles``` and ```bb``` and as there are distinct values for these two parameter for a given player they are kept. This would show unique values: ```bat_01 %>% select(playerID, mean_singles, mean_bb)) %>% unique()```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to get the table to look like? This seems to me like you probably want `summarize()` instead of `mutate()` for calculating `mean_singles` and `mean_bb`, but it's tough to tell without a description of what you're hoping for

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed